# Match everything Between two Characters except when there is a Blank line

Tags: javascript, php, regex, string

I am trying to find a regex pattern that matches everything between one or two dollar signs, `\$.*\$|\${2}.*\${2}`, except when there is a blank line (it's either two or one, can't be this: `\$.*\$\$`). Below, I provide examples of what I want to match and what I want to skip. The match should include/exclude everything.

#### Examples of what I want to match:

```
$$ \abc + ko$$
```

```
$*-ls$
```

Here the single dollar sign has a escape character before it so it won't break the match.

```
$$
654a\$
$$
```

```
$123
a*/\
[]{}$
```

#### Examples of what I want to exclude:

```
$$

asd
$$
```

```
$asdasd$$
```

Again, I want to match *everything* if they are bound by one $ or two $ at each side, unless there is (are) empty line(s) in between.

---

So far I figured out how to match the ones occurring in a single line, but I am struggling how to include break-line and exclude them if the whole line is empty.

Here is what I have:

```
^\${2}.*[^\\$]\${2}$|^\$.*[^\\$]\$$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vW4iR7/18)

Comment: Not sure if possessive quantifiers are supported, but perhaps like this `(?<!\S)(\$\$?+)[^\r\n$]*(?:\$(?!\$)[^\r\n$]*)*(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*$)[^\r\n$]*(?:\$(?!\$)[^\r\n$]*)*)*\1(?!\S)`  https://regex101.com/r/I2QTFJ/1

Comment: There is a space after `$$\n654\na`, is it intentional? If there can be initial/trailing horizontal whitespaces, you may try `/^[^\S\r\n]*(\${1,2})(?:(?!\1|^$)[\s\S])+?\1[^\S\r\n]*$/gm`, see https://regex101.com/r/AqZFPB/1.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew There's no limit on trailing spaces but leading spaces should not be more than 3. If there are 4 leading spaces then I don't want it to match, but this is already an amazing answer and that part is not important because it can (actually should) be taken care of by another regex. Would you post this as an answer?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Well this works ```/^[^\S\r\n]{0,3}(\${1,2})(?:(?!\1|^$)[\s\S])+?\1[^\S\r\n]*$/gm```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/^[^\S\r\n]{0,3}(\${1,2})(?:(?!\1|^$)[\s\S])+?\1[^\S\r\n]*$/gm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AqZFPB/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line (since `m` makes `^` match line start positions)
- `[^\S\r\n]{0,3}` - zero to three occurrences of any whitespace but CR and LF
- `(\${1,2})` - Group 1 holding one or two `$` chars
- `(?:(?!\1|^$)[\s\S])+?` - any char (`[\s\S]`), 1 or more occurrences, but as few as possible (due to the lazy `+?` quantifier), that does not start the same sequence as captured in Group 1 (`\1`) and a position between two line break chars (`^$`)
- `\1` - the same value as in Group 1 (`$` or `$$`)
- `[^\S\r\n]*` - zero or more occurrences of any whitespace but CR and LF
- `$` - end of a line (since `m` makes `^` match line start positions)

Answer (score 2):

For your example data, you might use

```
(?<!\S)(\$\$?+)[^\r\n$]*(?:\$(?!\$)[^\r\n$]*)*(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*$)[^\r\n$]*(?:\$(?!\$)[^\r\n$]*)*)*\1(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary on the left
- `(\$\$?+)` Capture group 1, match $ or $$ where the second one is possessive (prevent backtracking)
- `[^\r\n$]*(?:\$(?!\$)[^\r\n$]*)*` Match any char except `$` or newline or a $ when not directly followed by another `$`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*$)` Match a newline, assert not a line consisting of only spaces
  - `[^\r\n$]*(?:\$(?!\$)[^\r\n$]*)*` Same pattern as above
- `)*` Close the group and repeat 0+ times
- `\1` Backreference to what is captured in group 1
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary on the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tws7Pi/1)

Comment: Just so you know the purpose of this thread: https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/issues/182

Comment: @M-- For the pattern I have used the example data. My advice would be to test /write tests validating the expected results for your scenarios.

Comment: Actually I've been told that the userscript is using JS; thanks for the input though.